# Highchart - Activity guage display lable and lagends

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

I have used [Highchart](https://www.highcharts.com) javascript library for chart functionality.

Heare I required lagends and lables in highchart activity guage chart => [Highchart - Activity guage demo](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity).

Required output is display in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add labels use Highcharts.SVGRenderer:

```
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var x = this.plotWidth / 2 - 10,
                y;

            Highcharts.each(this.series, function(s) {
                y = s.group.getBBox().y + this.plotTop + 25;
                this.renderer
                    .text('dwa', x, y)
                    .attr({
                        align: 'right'
                    })
                    .add()
                    .toFront();
            }, this);
        }
    }
```

To show legend set `showInLegend` property in series to `true`.

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wpcLurtz/

Comment: Or you could use dataLabels, but you will still need to place them in a position - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yr23vzm5/